# How can I access controller properties from inside router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-controllers

I'm using willTransition hook inside my router as follows.

```
actions: {
        willTransition(transition) {
            this._super(...arguments);
            //some code goes here
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to access some property here  that is set from controller.

For example: inside my controller, i set value 500 to `someProperty` as follows.

```
this.set('someProperty', 500);
```

How can I access that value inside above method(within the router). Appreciate any help.

Comment: You mean you want to access the `controller` in the `route` and not in the `router`. There's a clear distinction between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `controller` property,

```
this.controller.set('someProperty',500)
```

Comment: Actually I want to get that value inside router. When I'm using `this.controller.get('someProperty')` it gives `undefined`

Comment: just do `console.log(' Controller properties ', this.controller);` and inspect what is going wrong ? is it the property name is not yet defined...You have one more option `this.controllerFor('routename')` will give controller instance